# Set textfield value from object retrieved via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have an object like this which I retrieve via an AJAX request:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Eyes"
}
```

How can I get that data for my text field `#id_attributes` and `#name_attributes`? I tried this when a button was clicked, but it gives me undefined/blank?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "to my json",
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: 'id=' + id,
    success: function (result) {              
        $("#id_attributes").val(result.id);
        $("#name_attributes").val(result.name);
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Daraformat i  the data: hould be in format {id:id} instead of 'id=' + id

Comment: There's no reason that JS code by itself would not work. Have you checked the console to make sure that the request is being completed successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "to my json",
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType : 'json'
    data:{id:id},
    success: function (result) {              
        $("#id_attributes").val(result.id);
        $("#name_attributes").val(result.name);
    }
});
```

or parse the result

```
success: function (result) {  
            var  jsonresult = JSON.parse(result);             
            $("#id_attributes").val(jsonresult.id);
            $("#name_attributes").val(jsonresult.name);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

add a [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) option

```
$.ajax({
    url: "to my json",
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType : 'json',
    data:'id='+id,
    success: function (result) {              
        $("#id_attributes").val(result.id);
        $("#name_attributes").val(result.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType: 'json'`:

```
type: "POST",
data: {"id": id},
dataType: 'json',
success: function (result) {
```